# How can I remove object from array, with Lodash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I'm trying to remove an object from an array using Lodash.

In `server.js` (using NodeJS):

```js
    var lodash = require('lodash')();

    var rooms = [
      { channel: 'room-a', name: 'test' },
      { channel: 'room-b', name: 'test' } 
    ]
```

I tried with two commands and it did not work:

```js
    var result = lodash.find(rooms, {channel: 'room-a', name:'test'});
    var result = lodash.pull(rooms, lodash.find(rooms, {channel: 'room-a', name:'test'}));
```

Here's the output of `console.log(result)`:

```
    LodashWrapper {
      __wrapped__: undefined,
      __actions__: [ { func: [Function], args: [Object], thisArg: [Object] } ],
      __chain__: false,
      __index__: 0,
      __values__: undefined }
```

Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: I wanted to avoid fatigue :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require('lodash')()
```

Calling the `lodash` function (by `()`) creates a LoDash object that wraps `undefined`.

That's not what you want; you want the `lodash` function itself, which contains static methods.

Remove that.

Comment: uoooWoww impressive, I do not have much knowledge, but it was just a detail! so I thought well with my code, it worked like a charm! thankyou @SLaks !!!!

Comment: For more details about LoDash wrapper objects (for chaining), see their docs.

Answer (score 20):

[_.remove()](https://lodash.com/docs#remove) is a good option.

```js
var rooms = [
  { channel: 'room-a', name: 'test' },
  { channel: 'room-b', name: 'test' } 
];

_.remove(rooms, {channel: 'room-b'});

console.log(rooms); //[{"channel": "room-a", "name": "test"}]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.14.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That wasn't clear in the docs! Was trying to combine with `filter` to no success

Answer (score 7):

I'd go for [reject()](https://lodash.com/docs#reject) in this scenario. Less code:

```
var result = _.reject(rooms, { channel: 'room-a', name: 'test' });
```